# Temporarily use a 16GB iPhone restoring data from a 64gb iPhone back up

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have to send my iPhone 64GB to repair and I will have to temporary use a 16GB device. The same problem was described in this [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7324634), but I am actually struggling to understand how to practically implement the solution, and what are eventually the consequences of these actions. Also another [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68971/can-i-restore-from-a-16gb-backup-to-an-8gb-iphone) mentioned something similar, but it relates to an older generation of software.

I backed up my phone on my PC using iTunes (no iCloud), for a total size of about 38GB. I would like to temporary activate my settings on a 16 GB phone without losing the possibility to later restore my full backup on my device once repaired. This would basically mean to restore my settings on the 16GB without transferring all the photos, videos, and other media contents.
The mentioned post suggests to " *sync it with iTunes or iCloud and move data manually*": what does this mean? Could you suggest a guide to do that? Would I lose the possibility to later restore this backup to my phone once repaired?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have iCloud enabled at all? Was your original phone using it?

Comment: Do a **full** backup. Then delete stuff in the phone leaving just what you need that fits 16GB and do a second backup.  Restore that second backup to the 16GB phone. Once you have the 64GB phone back restore from 1st backup - but make sure you get any fresh data from 16GB phone.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the hint. I have a doubt regarding the last step. How can you get the "fresh data" from the 16gb phone without overwriting the "old" full backup?

Comment: @Nemesi You can "lock" backups so that they won't be erased.